# When timer of other appdelegate called viewcontroller not changed as per my code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

When I click on start, event timer in appDelegate will start and after some time I have to show a view when timer fired.

my problem is that timer fired method is called but navigation not push the viewcontroller

```
-(IBAction)fakeCallCaled:(id)sender
{
      NSLog(@"FakeCall");
      fakeCallDesignViewController *fakeCallVC = [[fakeCallDesignViewController alloc]init];
      NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      [array addObjectsFromArray:navController.viewControllers];
      [array addObject:fakeCallVC];
      [navController setViewControllers:array];
      [array release];
      [fakeCallVC release];
}
```

this method is in delegate

in firstviewcontroller.m

```
 -(void)eventStarted
 {
        delegate.fakecallTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(fakeCallCaled:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
 }
```

now after 5 second i will get "FakeCall" in log but viewcontroller not change

i also try push in appdelegate

```
  -(IBAction)fakeCallCaled:(id)sender
  {
        NSLog(@"FakeCall");
        fakeCallDesignViewController *fakeCallVC = [[fakeCallDesignViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:fakeCallVC animated:NO];
        [fakeCallVC release];
  }
```

but I get the same result.

Comment: What does the `viewDidLoad` code of the `fakeCallDesignViewController` look like?

Comment: Also if your code `delegate.fakecallTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(fakeCallCaled:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];` is in the FirstViewController,  your selector method `fakeCallCaled:` should also be implemented in the same FirstViewController since you set the target as self.

Answer (score 0):

Why to use timer for such a task please use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(fakeCallCaled:) withObject:self afterDelay:5];
```

Comment: thanks for replay can we change application state   i mean from background mode to active mode programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can start using blocks for this. You dont need the `fakeCallCaled` method at all in this case. Just add the below code in your `eventStarted` method and it should work. And make sure that you are doing the UI work in main thread like this.

```
-(void)eventStarted
 {
   double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
   dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
   dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        NSLog(@"FakeCall");
        fakeCallDesignViewController *fakeCallVC = [[fakeCallDesignViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:fakeCallVC animated:NO];
        [fakeCallVC release];
   }); 
}
```

Comment: No it's not working..     and one more question can we change application state from background to active programmatically?

Comment: @Pratik, What is the error you are getting? Can you share some more details. You cant change the app state programmatically. User has to tap on home button to put it in background mode and they have to open the app again to put it in active mode.

Comment: i want app become active programmatically after some time

Comment: No, that is not possible in normal apps. Apple will never allow that. Can you please accept this answer. That will help many other people who are looking for the same answer. You can click on the tick mark next to this answer to accept it. This is the better way for you to push to a new view controller after a delay. But this will work only if the app is in active mode.